# How to upgrade Polaris?

Tags: css, reactjs, shopify, polaris

I have Shopify Polaris v6 installed, I checked the version accessing the import below and the file is saying v6.4.

```
import '@shopify/polaris/dist/styles.css';
```

How could I update my Shopify app to use Polaris v9?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to run this command below:

```
npm install @shopify/polaris@"9.16.0" --save
```

It will update your `package.json` file in the root folder. The CSS folder location changed in the version 9, so you will have to change your import to this new import:

```
import '@shopify/polaris/build/esm/styles.css';
```

You can check the lasted version of Polaris and all versions available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/polaris